# Strongly-Typed values in specflow scenario

Tags: specflow, feature-file

Is there any way to use Strongly-Typed values in *Examples* table of the scenario? (or alternative solution)

I'd like to know if I made a typo in `userType` column already during the coding (not during running the test).

UPDATED

**file.feature**

```
Scenario Outline: Scenario123
Given Create new user of type "<userType>"
Examples:
| userType     |
| PlatinumUser |
| CommonUser   |
```

**steps.cs**

```
[Given(@"Create new user of type ""(.*)""")]
public void CreateNewUser(UserTypeEnum userType)
{
    // some code like e.g.:
    MyUser user = new MyUser(userType);
    //...
}

enum UserTypeEnum  { CommonUser, PlatinumUser, Spectre }
```

Comment: This example looks a little too vague. I'm not clear about how you expect to map the table to strongly typed values.

Comment: Can you post more of the steps in your outline? How are each of these values used? Their types will be determined at test execution time by the step in which they are used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specflow supports **accepting strongly typed enum** values.
Though, the **scenario** sends it **as text** (case **insensitive**).

example:

```
    Scenario: Some enum test  
        When I send enum "Second"        
        Then I get the second enum
```

```
    public enum ChosenOption
    {
        First,
        Second,
        Third,
    }
    
    [When(@"I send enum ""(.*)""")]
    public void WhenISendEnum(ChosenOption option)
    {
        _scenarioContext.Set(option, nameof(ChosenOption));
    }

    [Then(@"I get the second enum")]
    public void ThenIGetTheSecondEnum()
    {
        var chosen = _scenarioContext.Get<ChosenOption>(nameof(ChosenOption));
        chosen.Should().Be(ChosenOption.Second);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like its a StepArgumentTransformation that you are after?

https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Step-Argument-Conversions

Used somehow along these lines:

```
[Binding]
public class Transforms
{
    [StepArgumentTransformation]
    public UserTypeEnum UserTypeTransform(string UserType)
    {
      // return the string converted into the required Enum
    }
}
```

The step binding will see that it requires a UserTypeEnum as a parameter so it will search for all the available Step Argument Transformations within any classes with the Binding attribute and use this method to perform the conversion.